# Mysql sort by user defined advanced

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

Apologies if this question has already been answered, I've already done an extensive search but haven't come across an answer.
Is it possible to do an alphabetical sort by with own defined.

Example items with cell `name`:

Sort By `name` ASC:

```
Brand1 Model1 Premium
Brand1 Model1 Standard
Brand1 Model1 Normal
Brand1 Model2 Normal
Brand1 Model2 Premium
Brand1 Model2 Standard
Brand1 Model3 Normal
Brand1 Model3 Premium
Brand1 Model3 Standard
```

But I want defined own order example:

```
Brand1 Model2 Premium <- model2 firt and best version
Brand1 Model2 Normal <- model2 next alphabetical order
Brand1 Model2 Standard <- model2 next alphabetical order
Brand1 Model1 Premium <- model2 next alphabetical by premium first
Brand1 Model1 Normal
Brand1 Model1 Standard
Brand1 Model3 Premium
Brand1 Model3 Normal
Brand1 Model3 Standard
```

I try used like as:

```
Case `name`
    when "Brand1 Model2 Premium" then 1
    when "Brand1 Model2 %" then 2
    when "Brand1 Model1 Premium" then 3
    when "Brand1 Model1 %" then 4
    when "Brand1 Model% Premium" then 5 <- next normal sorting only by 
    when "Brand1 Model%" then 6
    else 7
end,
```

Of course Brand, Model and version is one cell. Exactly it's name of product. I don't explode product name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `name` value pattern is fixed as `brandX modelY Type`, then following solution should work.

Use `ORDER BY FIELD` on splitting the `name` into desired words order.

**Example**:

```
select name from (
  select name
   , @s1:=substring( name, locate( ' ', name )+1 ) s1 -- ModelY Premium/Normal/Standard
   , @s2:=substring_index( @s1, ' ', 1 ) s2           -- ModelY
   , @s3:=substring_index( @s1, ' ', -1 ) s3          -- Premium/Normal/Standard
  from table_name
) segregated_name_results
order by 
 field( s2, 'Model2', 'Model1', 'Model3' )
 , field( s3, 'Premium', 'Normal', 'Standard' )
;

+------------------------+
| name                   |
+------------------------+
| Brand1 Model2 Premium  |
| Brand1 Model2 Normal   |
| Brand1 Model2 Standard |
| Brand1 Model1 Premium  |
| Brand1 Model1 Normal   |
| Brand1 Model1 Standard |
| Brand1 Model3 Premium  |
| Brand1 Model3 Normal   |
| Brand1 Model3 Standard |
+------------------------+
```

**Reference Values on Sub-query**:

```
select name
 , @s1:=substring( name, locate( ' ', name )+1 ) s1
 , @s2:=substring_index( @s1, ' ', 1 ) s2
 , @s3:=substring_index( @s1, ' ', -1 ) s3
from brand_models

+------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------+
| name                   | s1              | s2     | s3       |
+------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------+
| Brand1 Model1 Premium  | Model1 Premium  | Model1 | Premium  |
| Brand1 Model1 Standard | Model1 Standard | Model1 | Standard |
| Brand1 Model1 Normal   | Model1 Normal   | Model1 | Normal   |
| Brand1 Model2 Normal   | Model2 Normal   | Model2 | Normal   |
| Brand1 Model2 Premium  | Model2 Premium  | Model2 | Premium  |
| Brand1 Model2 Standard | Model2 Standard | Model2 | Standard |
| Brand1 Model3 Normal   | Model3 Normal   | Model3 | Normal   |
| Brand1 Model3 Premium  | Model3 Premium  | Model3 | Premium  |
| Brand1 Model3 Standard | Model3 Standard | Model3 | Standard |
+------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------+
```

**Demo** @ [***MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/289af/1)

Comment: Tomorrow check your solution. Today, I am already too tired to adapt next version :)

Comment: Exactly! Thanks this solution 2 with order by field desc is almost perfect. The rest of "exceptions" will pick up by php.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
order by substring_index(name, ' ', 2),
         (case when substring_index(name, ' ', -1) = 'Premium' then 1
               when substring_index(name, ' ', -1) = 'Standard' then 2
               when substring_index(name, ' ', -1) = 'Normal' then 3
          end)
```

This assumes that the special string ("premium" and so on) is at the end of the `name` and the first two words are sufficient for sorting the name column otherwise.